# Is there any equivalent of XAMPP for Pylons?

Tags: apache, pylons

I'd like to get started with Pylons, to be used on a Windows machine as a local web server. Is there any equivalent of e.g. XAMPP for Pylons that would set up everything with one installer?

**Edit:** I've just discovered the [Pylons web server](http://pylonshq.com/features). Could I use this to serve pages to computers on a LAN?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is use [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) with XAMPP. Unfortunately I am not aware of any installers for that combination.

You almost never want to use the web server built into the framework, but Pylons uses [Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/), which is quite a bit more capable than most stock web servers so that could be an acceptable alternative if you don't need `httpd`.

Answer (score 0):

pylons can be installed using easy_install or unzipping the tarball and running "python setup.py install" (like any python package).

the great google god machine says it's possible to run a wsgi app under IIS([shudder](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Serving+a+Pylons+app+with+IIS)),

other than that, once you have your pylons application written, consider running it as a [windows service](http://islascruz.org/html/index.php?gadget=StaticPage&action=Page&id=6)